# facebook reaction buttons / javascript gets called only once in PHP loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, facebook

I'm trying integrate facebook animated reaction emoji's to my website and suprised that there are not many sources about it. Actually I'm almost done. I found nice script and modified it in parts to my purpose and happy to share it with you. But it only works in the way I want for one post. There is a problem when the page has multiple posts that can be liked. I ve found that javascript doesnt gets called more than one times inside php loop and dont know why. I both tried to keep javascript externally and internally. Didnt work. Here is my code. For demo purpose I have added some php lines inside html section in snippet. Any ideas?

```js
'use strict';
(function() {
  var likeLink = document.querySelector('.Like__link');
  likeLink.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
    likeLink.classList.remove('js-hover');
  });
  likeLink.classList.remove('js-hover');

}());
```

```css
.Like {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 5rem;
}
.Like__link {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.Emojis {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 120%;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-10%, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(-10%, 0, 0);
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  padding: .125rem;
  border-radius: 100rem;
  -webkit-transition: .3s .3s;
  transition: .3s .3s;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08), 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.Emojis:hover,
.Like__link.js-hover ~ .Emojis,
.Like__link:hover ~ .Emojis {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
  transition-delay: 0s;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
.Emoji {
  position: relative;
  width: 3rem;
  height: 3rem;
  color: #ffd972;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition-delay: .6s, .3s;
  transition-delay: .6s, .3s;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0s, .3s;
  transition-duration: 0s, .3s;
  -webkit-transition-property: opacity, -webkit-transform;
  transition-property: opacity, -webkit-transform;
  transition-property: transform, opacity;
  transition-property: transform, opacity, -webkit-transform;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0) scale(0.3);
  transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0) scale(0.3);
}
.Emojis:hover .Emoji,
.Like__link.js-hover + .Emojis .Emoji,
.Like__link:hover + .Emojis .Emoji {
  -webkit-transform: none;
  transform: none;
  opacity: 1;
}
.Emoji .icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
  transform: scale(0.8);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .2s ease;
  transition: -webkit-transform .2s ease;
  transition: transform .2s ease;
  transition: transform .2s ease, -webkit-transform .2s ease;
}
.Emoji:hover .icon {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1) translate3d(0, -10%, 0);
  transform: scale(1) translate3d(0, -10%, 0);
}
.Emojis:hover .Emoji:nth-of-type(1),
.Like__link:hover + .Emojis .Emoji:nth-of-type(1) {
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
  transition-delay: 0s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.6, 0.6, 0.5, 1);
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.6, 0.6, 0.5, 1);
}
.Emojis:hover .Emoji:nth-of-type(2),
.Like__link:hover + .Emojis .Emoji:nth-of-type(2) {
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.02s;
  transition-delay: 0.02s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.6, 0.6, 0.5, 1.2);
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.6, 0.6, 0.5, 1.2);
}
.Emojis:hover .Emoji:nth-of-type(3),
.Like__link:hover + .Emojis .Emoji:nth-of-type(3) {
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.04s;
  transition-delay: 0.04s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.6, 0.6, 0.5, 1.4);
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.6, 0.6, 0.5, 1.4);
}
.Emojis:hover .Emoji:nth-of-type(4),
.Like__link:hover + .Emojis .Emoji:nth-of-type(4) {
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.06s;
  transition-delay: 0.06s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.6, 0.6, 0.5, 1.6);
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.6, 0.6, 0.5, 1.6);
}
.Emojis:hover .Emoji:nth-of-type(5),
.Like__link:hover + .Emojis .Emoji:nth-of-type(5) {
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.6s;
  transition-duration: 0.6s;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.08s;
  transition-delay: 0.08s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.6, 0.6, 0.5, 1.8);
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.6, 0.6, 0.5, 1.8);
}
.Emojis:hover .Emoji:nth-of-type(6),
.Like__link:hover + .Emojis .Emoji:nth-of-type(6) {
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.7s;
  transition-duration: 0.7s;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.1s;
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.6, 0.6, 0.5, 2);
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.6, 0.6, 0.5, 2);
}
.Emoji--like {
  /* color: $c-blue; */
}
.Emoji--love {
  /* color: $c-red; */
}
.icon {
  background-image: url("https://media.giphy.com/media/xT9DPr2QnsfTFoykFO/giphy.gif");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.icon--like {
  background-position: -6px -6px;
}
.icon--heart {
  background-position: -68px -4px;
}
.icon--haha {
  background-position: -129px -6px;
}
.icon--wow {
  background-position: -191px -6px;
}
.icon--sad {
  background-position: -252px -5px;
}
.icon--angry {
  background-position: -314px -6px;
}
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #222;
  text-align: center;
}
.intro {
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 30rem;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  margin: 0 auto 1em;
  padding-top: .5em;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
.intro small {
  display: block;
  opacity: .5;
  font-style: italic;
  text-transform: none;
}
.info {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1em;
  font-size: .9em;
  font-style: italic;
  font-family: serif;
  text-align: right;
  opacity: .5;
}
.info a {
  color: inherit;
}
kbd {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  color: #666;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px #fff;
  padding: 1px 4px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 3px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <title>TODO supply a title</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
  <?php //queries here. $entries=... foreach ($entries as $item) { ?>
  <!-- beginning of foreach loop-->
  <script>
    // in normal this block is activeve to prevent initial appear but commented now.  
     // var likeLink = document.querySelector('.Like__link');                             likeLink.classList.remove('js-hover');
  </script>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="Like"><a class="Like__link js-hover">Like <kbd>hover me!!</kbd></a>
      <div class="Emojis">

        <div class="Emoji Emoji--like">
          <div class="icon icon--like"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="Emoji Emoji--love">
          <div class="icon icon--heart"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="Emoji Emoji--haha">
          <div class="icon icon--haha"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="Emoji Emoji--wow">
          <div class="icon icon--wow"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="Emoji Emoji--sad">
          <div class="icon icon--sad"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="Emoji Emoji--angry">
          <div class="icon icon--angry"></div>
        </div>
        <script>
          // in normal Im putting the javascript here. and it gets called only one for some raeson.
        </script>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <?php } ?>
  <!-- end of foreach loop-->
</body>

</html>
```

[reference of the code](https://codepen.io/mohamed-elhussini/pen/vGjmdr)

Comment: Put the script out of loop and instead use javascript `.each` on desired elements as a javascript loop.

Comment: I aggree with @Ali Sheikhpour, if you put some JavaSrcipt in a PHP loop, the effect is that your JavaScript will be outputted as many time as you have rows... So `var` definitions will be repeated many times for the same variable.... And functions too. I think **this** is your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should **not** insert Javascript `functions` inside a PHP while fetch loop.

The effect is to output your functions as many time as you have rows.

So something like this will obviously not work:

```
<script>
function something(){
    // code
}
</script>

<!-- some HTML for row[0]-->

<script>
function something(){
    // code
}
</script>

<!-- some HTML for row[1]-->

<script>
function something(){
    // code
}
</script>

<!-- some HTML for row[2]-->

<!-- and so on... -->
```

You should see right away that the function `something()` is defined more than one time...
And this is bad.
I think that **THIS IS** the problem you're facing.